# How works laravel session storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Session::put('name','value')` method to set session in laravel. But when I go to browser developer tools and check session storage there is nothing. Why is that? where is that session data saved

Comment: The session settings for Laravel are configured in `config/app`, so review that and you should see where it's stored. Generally, it's in `storage/framework/sessions`

Comment: Laravel is use for server side development.it is not any front end framework like react angular and vue js which will store session in session storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see session data, you can use [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to debug sessions, cache, logs, routes, views etc.

[image: laravel-debugbar]

**To install:**

```sh
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"
```

You will get a `debugbar.php` in your `config` folder, open it and configure what you want to debug.

Make sure `APP_DEBUG` is set to `true` in your `.env` file for it to work.

View the website and you will see the debugbar at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question, please mark is as the correct answer below the arrows :) Will also help the next visitor.